# Find all elements that don't contain a certain string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to select all elements with a certain class, but not if they contain certain `.text()`?

Here is what I have so far -

```
<div class="test">0</div>
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>

var divList = $(".test").toArray();
var divLength = divList.length;
```

What I want to do with this code is to not include the `<div>` with the 0 in it.

Comment: You can also directly access `.length` on a jQuery object.

Comment: you're going to have problems if one of those divs has a `0` anywhere in the text. as far as i know, `:contains` can't take a regex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('.test').not(':contains(0)')
```

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Incidentally, to answer epascarello's question, this will match ANY substring ANYWHERE inside the element. If your numbers go up to 10, it will match and discount that one as well. You'll need a custom selector or a `.filter()` function if that's an issue for you.

Comment: +1, much faster than the single-selector syntax (on chrome atleast) http://jsperf.com/psuedo-vs-chained-jb

Comment: @jbabey I'm not surprised -- parsing the selector means extra work by the jQuery engine to get the same result. Of course, in the real world, there's unlikely to be any perceptible difference.

Answer (score 3):

A quick google brought this to the surface http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-opposite-of-contains

It comes down to this

```
$(".test:not(:contains('0'))")
```

**EDIT**

A test by @jbabey shows that the accepted answer is faster, so use that

```
$(".test").not(":contains(0)");
```

As a followup on epascarello's answer, the following selector will do an exact match (this is not included in jQuery by default!)

```
$.expr[":"].econtains = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
    return (obj.textContent || obj.innerText || $(obj).text() || "").toLowerCase() == meta[3].toLowerCase();
}
```

To do an exact match, you can now use

```
$(".test").not(":econtains(0)");​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
$(".test:not(:contains('0'))")
```

Comment: +1 for a correct answer and to counteract the random commentless downvoter.

Comment: @jbabey:- Thanx a lot. I misunderstood the question previosuly maybe thats why i got downvote :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that does not use `:contains` selector

You can use `.filter()` function

```
$('.test').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().indexOf('0') < 0 ;
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/AYCw2/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is also one of the way to get the desired text: http://jsbin.com/arifuv/1/edit

```
var aa = $('.test').filter(':not(:contains(0))').text();

console.log(aa);

// results are ---> 1234
```